# select rows from SQL table and 5 rows from another

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have three SQL server tables like this [image]

i need to select the `categories from LS_categoires  where nodeid = 183` and `select only 5  files from LS_files` that related to each category was selected

**if i have two categories related to `node 183` the result should be `10 rows`** 
is that possible ?

Comment: How the table `LS_Files` relates to the `LS_Items_Types`? by which key? it isn't clear from the image.

Comment: `R1` - `R5` looks suspiciously like something that ought to be a set of rows in a separate table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SELECT
  *  
FROM LS_Categories c 
INNER JOIN
( 
   SELECT 
     *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY catid
                          ORDER BY item_id ASC) rownum
   FROM LS_ItemTypes
) l  ON c.catid = l.catid
    AND l.rownum <= 5
INNER JOIN LS_Files f ON l.item_id = f.id
where c.nodeid = 183;
```

This will select first files for each category.

Comment: i dont have item_id column in Ls_categories table

Comment: @M.NourBerro It depends on how much data do you have in your tables. But, this solution will be the best performance wise, and there is no way to do so without the function `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ...` AFAIK.

Comment: i need a count of files how can i do that, is there another way tan write subquery (select count(*) from LS_files where l.catid= c.catid) as counts)

Comment: @M.NourBerro Do you mean within the same query you need to get the count of files? or this is a different query?

Comment: @M.NourBerro But this query will give you only five files for each category, so you need to count them or count all the files that this category has? Sorry but I couldn't understand.

Comment: i need the same result if i add the subquery (select count(*) from LS_files where l.catid= c.catid) as counts)
in the first line of your code

Comment: @M.NourBerro OK, you can select `COUNT(f.*)` in the same query, but you will need a add a `GROUP BY` clause and add other columns that you add in the `SELECT` clause, otherwise add them in an aggregate function.